# Объединение строк в текстовом файле

Tags: perl, объединение

Подскажите, есть ли какой либо однострочник Perl, что бы считать фаил и объеденить несколько строк в одну.
Например, в txt следующий контент

```
123abc
456def
789000
abc123
def456
000989
```

Нужно сделать что бы в выходном файле были записи,объединенные по 3 строки:

```
123abc456def789000, abc123def456000989
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В одну строку, так в одну строку

```
perl -e "$str='';$i=0;while(<>){$_=~s/\s//gms;$str.=$_;$i++;if($i>2){print(\"$str \");$str='';$i=0;}}" < test1.txt
```

test1.txt:

```
123abc
456def
789000
abc123
def456
000989
```

Вывод: 123abc456def789000 abc123def456000989

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо